# Object cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted error

Tags: c++, clang

In my small arkanoid clone game I'm trying to erase some values from a vector. This vector contains Brick classes, that are instantiated on the screen in a grid like pattern. When a collision happens between the ball and a brick, the brick needs to disappear. I'm trying to accomplish this with this small piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bricks.size(); ++i)
{
    if (bricks[i].destroyed)
    {
        bricks.erase(bricks.begin()+i);
    }
}
```

But unfortunately I get this compile error:

```
Object of type 'Brick' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
```

When I click on this error it brings me to this piece of code:

```
for (; __first != __last; ++__first, (void) ++__result)
    *__result = _VSTD::move(*__first);
return __result;
```

Can somebody give me advice how to solve this?

Comment: What does `Brick` look like?

Comment: Note that your loop is wrong. If you erase the n'th element you then move onto the n'th + 1 element. However, the process of erasing mvoes the original n+1 element down into the n'th space and so you dont destroy it. A canonical way would be to use iterators and assign the return value for erase to the iterator OR call ++iterator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can somebody give me advice how to solve this?

When you delete a non last element in a `std::vector`, it has to move all elements behind it. It can be done either by move-assignment (for C++11 or later) or copy assignment operator for an element. So to solve it, you either need to provide such operator for class `Brick`, use container that does not have to move elements like `std::list` or `std::set` etc or store smart pointers instead of objects themselv.