# C++ Vector erase is not working (semantic issues)

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm rewriting a code I need for school but my erase function isn't working and I don't know why is this happening; the code works in the old version.

Xcode gives me the following error:

> Object of type 'PlayLiszt' cannot be assigned because its copy
>   assignment operator is implicitly deleted

When I comment this function the code compiles again. Any help is much appreciated.

```
void eliminarElemento(std::vector<PlayLiszt>& usrPlaylist){
    mostrarElementos(usrPlaylist);
    bool invalidValue = true;
    while (invalidValue) {
        std::cout << "Elije elemento a eliminar: ";
        int elementoABorrar;
        std::cin >> elementoABorrar;
        if (elementoABorrar >= 0 and elementoABorrar < usrPlaylist.size()) {
            usrPlaylist.erase(usrPlaylist.begin()+(elementoABorrar-1));
            std::cout << "Elemento Eliminado!" << std::endl;
            invalidValue = false;
        } else {
            invalidValue = true;
            std::cout << "Ese elemento no existe!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in this line:

```
usrPlaylist.erase(usrPlaylist.begin()+(elementoABorrar-1));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752505/object-cannot-be-assigned-because-its-copy-assignment-operator-is-implicitly-del)

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Does `PlayLiszt` have a copy assignment operator?

Comment: I would also be concerned about someone entering a zero, and the code then trying to delete `usrPlaylist.begin() - 1`.

Comment: Your problem is *triggered* by said line, it's not *in* that line.

Comment: No [MCVE], no service.

Comment: btw is that name a reference to Franz Liszt, or a typo?